# JavaScriptオブジェクトは値でソートできる？

Tags: javascript

**JavaScriptオブジェクトは、仕様ではキーの順序を保証しなかったと思うのですが、値だとどうなるのですか？**

・下記で試してみた限りは期待した結果を得られたのですが、仕様的には問題ないですか？
・下記は、そもそも配列をソートしているだけなので、オブジェクトの順序とは無関係？？

```
let hoge = [
    {a: "あ", b: 1},
    {a: "い", b: 2}
];
hoge.sort(function(value1, value2) {
    return value2.b - value1.b;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ・下記は、そもそも配列をソートしているだけなので、オブジェクトの順序とは無関係？？

そう思います。配列を`各要素.b`でソートしているだけです。

> 仕様ではキーの順序を保証しなかったと思うのですが、値だとどうなるのですか？

上記の意味があまり理解できていませんが、
オブジェクトのキー一覧やオブジェクトの値一覧は以下のように取得でき、
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)によると、いずれも`for...in` ループによる順序と同じで、順不同(注)となるようです。

```
Object.keys(hoge[0])   //=> [ 'a', 'b' ]
Object.values(hoge[0]) //=> [ 'い', 2 ]
```

#### 注) 順不同について

[Javascriptにおけるオブジェクトの順序](https://qiita.com/suguru03/items/bf48610225fefcb0f45e)に検証された記事があります。
JavaScriptのエンジンにより挙動が違うようです。詳細は前述の記事などを参照ください。

以下はnodejs(v9.3.0)での実行例です。

```
obj = {a: "あ", b: 1}
console.log(Object.keys(obj)) //=> ['a', 'b']

obj.d = 2
obj.c = 3
console.log(Object.keys(obj)) //=> [ 'a', 'b', 'd', 'c' ]

obj[2] = "a"
obj[1] = "b"
console.log(Object.keys(obj)) //=> [ '1', '2', 'a', 'b', 'd', 'c' ]
```

Comment: 現実には普通によく使われているブラウザでは、上の例では殆ど同じ順番で出てくるようです。「順不同」というのを「ランダムな順番で出てくる」と誤解する人もいるので、「仕様としてはどんな順序になるか決まっていないこと」を表しているのだと言うのは触れておいた方が良いように思います。

Comment: @OOPer さん ご指摘ありがとうございます。順不同について追記しました。

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます。検証記事のリンクも挙げていただいたので、かなりわかりやすくなったように思います。

Comment: 「順不同」部分についての関連回答その1です: [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23202095/5989200)

Comment: 「順不同」部分についての関連回答その2です: [Does ES6 introduce a well-defined order of enumeration for object properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30076219/5989200)